# Should double glazing sit evenly in brick to brick window space?

Tags: windows, pvc, replacement

I've just had double glazing installed and I'm not entirely happy, but it could be my expectations are set too high.

The picture below shows my new sash window for the front room bay window. This is a brick to brick installation in a Victorian house. From the front of the house the window looks fine, but inside the frame is not lined up evenly. The frame is only visible to the right of the window, the left side of the frame disappears into the wall. I imagined the window would line up in the middle?

Is this kind of issue expected in a 100 year old house which are off square? Or are there ways to make the window hole square so everything fits properly? Have the windows firm measured the window properly?

[image: window from inside]

[image: window from outside]

Comment: Probably a case where the window can look good from the outside, or the inside but not both due to the way the house was constructed. They chose to not make it look like an eyesore from the outside where everyone walking by would notice it. It's one of the irritating factors of retrofitting something into something that was never built to those dimensions. You would need to hire a finish carpenter to widen the interior opening to give it that aesthetic balance as long as brickwork would allow it.

Comment: I agree with @fiasco labs' comment. That deserves to be posted as the answer.

Comment: @john - Posted as requested.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a case where the window can look good from the outside, or the inside but not both due to the way the house was constructed.

They chose to not make it look like an eyesore from the outside where everyone walking by would notice it.

It's one of the irritating factors of retrofitting something into something that was never built to those dimensions. You would need to hire a finish carpenter to widen the interior opening to give it that aesthetic balance as long as brickwork would allow it.